# Making parts of equations larger

Tags: math-mode, fontsize

Is there a way to make only a part of an equation larger? I'm working with the code below, but I feel like the s-angle-n and a-angle-n are far too small and would really like to make them both bigger without affecting the rest of the equation.

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\lcroof}[1]{
  \hbox{\vtop{\vbox{%
      \hrule\kern 1pt\hbox{%
        $\scriptstyle #1$%
        \kern 1pt}}\kern1pt}%
    \vrule\kern1pt}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\angle}[1]{
  _{\lcroof{#1}}}


\begin{align*}
s\angle{n}&=\dfrac{(1+r)^n-1}{r}\\
a\angle{n}&=\dfrac{1-\dfrac{1}{(1+r)^n}}{r}
\end{align*}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: How much bigger would be better than "far too small"?

Comment: They seem to have the proper size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about put them in text mode and then use \Huge, \Large, etc.

```
\begin{align*}
\mbox{\Huge{$s\angle{n}$}}  &=  \dfrac{(1+r)^n -1}{r}  \\
\mbox{\Huge{$a\angle{n}$}}  &=  \dfrac{1 - \dfrac{1}{(1+r)^n}}{r}
\end{align*}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the nicest solution, but you could use: `\usepackage{graphicx}`, and then have:

```
\begin{align*}
    \scalebox{1.5}{$s\angle{n}$}  &=  \dfrac{(1+r)^n -1}{r}  \\
    \scalebox{1.5}{$a\angle{n}$}  &=  \dfrac{1 - \dfrac{1}{(1+r)^n}}{r}
\end{align*}
```

Where you can change the 1.5 to suit your taste.